# Insert data using database class and function and getting error " call to member function Prepare() on string...database->insert("category",Array)

Tags: php, database, function, class, oop

Before Marking my question as duplicate please give any example or link where i can understand, i am learning PHP. hope you understand.

I am Trying to insert data using database_class and insert function.

Here's my database class.

```
//db_class.php
class database {

    var $_sql           = '';   
    var $_resource      = '';
    var $_result        = '';
    var $_insertId      = ''; 

    function connect() {
            
            global $glob;

        $host = $glob['localhost'];
        $user = $glob['root'];
        $pass = $glob[''];
        $db = $glob['crestdb'];
        
        try {
            $this->_resource = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';port=3306;dbname='.$db.'', $user, $pass);
            $this->_resource->query("SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1");
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            die();
        }   
    }

    function insert($table, $dbFields) {
    
        $field = array();
        $value = array();
        
        foreach ( $dbFields as $k => $v) {
            //$v = addslashes(stripslashes($v));
            $v = (stripslashes($v));
            $field[] = $k;
            $qmark[] =":".$k;
            $value[":".$k] = $v;            
        }

        $f = implode('`,`',$field);
        $val = implode("','",$value);
        $q = implode(",",$qmark);
        
        $insertSql = "INSERT INTO `$table` (`$f`) VALUES ($q)"; 
            
        $stmt = $this->_resource->prepare($insertSql);
        $stmt->execute($value);
        $_result=$this->_resource->lastInsertId();
        $this->_insertId=$_result;
        return $_result;
        
    }
```

**and am using it as**
***addcat.php***

```
include( "db_class.php");

$obj = new database(); 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$dbFields = array(
                 'cname' => $_POST['cname'],
                 'priority' =>$_POST['priority'],
                 'status' =>  $_POST['status'],           
           );
$obj->insert("category",$dbFields);
}
```

using this i am getting error as per my TITLE suggest.
i think i am making mistake in addcat.php am i calling this function wrongly?

this is the error:- Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\def\database.class.php:82 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\def\addcat.php(42): database->insert('category', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\def\database.class.php on line

Comment: `$_resource      = ''` so it's a string and you need to change this before using `->prepare`

Comment: You might want to change `connect()` to `__construct()` so that the connection is created when you instantiate the class.

Comment: It may be worth reading https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/ and check your code as the style is fairly outdated. (class names, usage of `var` etc.).  Also try and avoid using things like `global $glob;`.

Comment: @NigelRen, Sure i will keep in mind for the next time .

Answer (score 0):

By searching lot in google i tried to make different class for connection.
and @Felippe and @Aynber you both were right i have made an class using your suggestion.

```
class database{

 var $_resource ;

 var $_result    = '';
 var $_sql       = '';  
 var $_insertId  = '';
 
 var $host = 'localhost';  
 var $user = 'root' ;  
 var $pass = '';  
 var $dbname = 'crestdb';

 var $error;

public function __construct(){  
// Set DSN  
$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;  
// Set options  
$options = array(  
PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,  
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION  
);  
// Create a new PDO instanace  
try{  
$this->_resource = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);  
}  
// Catch any errors  
catch(PDOException $e){  
$this->error = $e->getMessage();  
}  
}
```

maybe it still  needs improvement but it works for me now !!.